# Why is the loss becoming NaN during training in my Keras model?

Tags: python, keras, nan, loss-function

I am training a Keras model with complex input data using the CVNN library. However, during training, the loss becomes NaN after the first epoch. Here is the relevant code:

```
import cvnn.layers as complex_layers

def createSB_cart(inp_shape, classes_num=2, emb_size=64, weight_decay=1e-4, classification=False):
    tf.device("gpu:1")
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexInput(input_shape=inp_shape))

    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv1D(32, 3, activation='cart_leaky_relu', padding='same',
                                           kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
                                           bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))

    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexAvgPooling1D(3))

    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv1D(16, 3, activation='cart_leaky_relu', padding='same',
                                           kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
                                           bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))

    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexAvgPooling1D(3))

    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexFlatten())

    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDropout(0.5))

    if classification:
        model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDense(classes_num, activation='convert_to_real_with_abs'))
    else:
        model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDense(classes_num, activation='linear',
                                              kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01),
                                              bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))

    return model

model = createSB_cart((None, 288, 1))
model.compile(loss=ComplexAverageCrossEntropy(), metrics=["accuracy"], optimizer="RMSprop")

model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=64, validation_data=(val_data, val_labels), callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

During the first epoch, the loss and accuracy seem reasonable:

Copy code
`Epoch 1/10 200/201 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6407 - accuracy: 0.6727   Epoch 1: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.73798, saving model to \rd3\res_out\modelDir\IQ_model_out_1_complex_after_fft_slices_10000_startIdx_300000_stride_72_len_288_STFT_64.h5 201/201 [==============================] - 13s 54ms/step - loss: 0.6408 - accuracy: 0.6728 - val_loss: 0.6479 - val_accuracy: 0.7380`

However, during the second epoch, the loss becomes NaN:

`Epoch 2/10 200/201 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6870     Epoch 2: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.73798 201/201 [==============================] - 11s 54ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6870 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000`

Here are data format:

> [6.1042188e-03+2.3257346e-03j  9.7109042e-03+2.3132132e-03j
> -3.8796104e-03-5.0874162e-03j ...  1.6878978e-03-5.0258427e-03j
> -5.7956297e-04+3.6877338e-03j  7.4644829e-03-4.2452393e-03j]

I am not sure what is causing the loss to become NaN. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.